# Node.js - Getting the host IP address while on Amazon EC2

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip-address

How can I get the IP address (elastic IP) of the current Node.js host/server on Amazon EC2?

Calling req.connection.address() is useless because EC2 uses an elastic IP. In fact, the IP that shows up using the ifconfig command is not the same as the IP which was used to access the server from outside (which is what I need). How can I get the elastic IP automatically?

Answer (score 2):

From within the instance, you can query for metadata about the instance by sending requests to `http://169.254.169.254`.

More information can be found here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AESDG-chapter-instancedata.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use **DescribeInstances** in the API as per the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-DescribeInstances.html) using the filter **ip-address** to get the public IP of your instance.

Answer (score 1):

Reading about headers and about elastic IP's, I would suggest that `headers['REMOTE_ADDR']` gives the address you're looking for (unless behind a load balancer).